# name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm getting this error "name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined" and am not able to find a solution on the Internet.

The full code can be found here: https://dzlab.github.io/jekyll/update/2018/11/13/audio-classification/.

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_lists(path, fnames, labels, ds_tfms=None, size=224, bs=bs)
data.normalize(imagenet_stats)
data.show_batch(rows=5, figsize=(8,8))
```

I'm running this code on Google Colab and Python 3.6.

Comment: Show **your** full code here (as text). It's not possible to say anything about this error without the full context

Comment: Presumably it's a class that you're supposed to import, and the example code omitted that detail.

Comment: @rdas I've uploaded my Colab notebook on Github. You can view the full code here: https://github.com/sunnysinghnitb/google_colab_notes/blob/master/Freesound_Audio_Tagging_2019.ipynb

Comment: As @JohnGordon pointed out, you don't have any import or definition for the `ImageDataBunch` symbol. Hence the error. I think this is the notebook you're trying to reproduce: https://github.com/dzlab/deepprojects/blob/master/classification/Freesound_General_Purpose_Audio_Tagging.ipynb Check the imports in it.

Comment: Great @rdas! After importing the dependencies, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to import the `ImageDataBunch` class from the fast.ai library. Here's the [docs](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.data.html#ImageDataBunch) for it. Just add the following to the top of your code to import the entirety of the vision library classes:

```
from fastai.vision import *
```

Comment: Found this page because I'm having this error, but already have this import specified. :-/

Comment: `from fastai import *`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
from fastai.vision.data import ImageDataBunch
```

this code will solve the problem